# How do I get clangd to also recognise c++ includes?

Tags: filetype-c++, mason, clangd

I've installed clangd through mason, the lsp works when I open a cpp file. It finds includes from the C std library but when I include  for instance it will just say `'fstream' file not found`, same goes for 'ostream' (which is included in a library I'd like to use'.

I'm using a PopOs distro and neovim is at version 0.9.1 any help would be greatly appreciated!

I don't know if this is relevant, but I compiled a starter program using g++ using the library that includes ostream, and the program compiled without a hitch. So I'm hoping I just have to add an include path setting or install the clang version of the stdlib but so far I haven't had any luck with those.

Comment: How do you include `fstream`: `#include <fstream>` vs. `#include "fstream"`? What is the symptom that made you believe the include is not accepted?

Comment: Tried this https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc ?

Comment: Showing how you build your library may also be important. Does this also occur if you run `clangd` outside of Vim? In fact, I think this is actually a clang question and should be asked on [so].